# How to automatically and efficiently determine number of cluster for K-means clustering algorithm using Knee algorithm?

Tags: python, k-means

I want to determine number of cluster (`K`) for K-means algorithm automatically, and the `wcss` for the chosen K to be less than a threshold. To do so, I am using [`Knee`](https://github.com/arvkevi/kneed) algorithm. However, it is really time-consuming when the dataset is large and my criteria is not satisfied when `wcss` computed for a small range for `K`, as I should increase the range to increase the chance of `K` satisfying my criteria. As a result, I have to cluster the large dataset with K-means and compute its `wcss` for a large range of possible K (e.g, `for k in range(1,1000)`). As the `knee` algorithm couldn't find best `K` unless I have computed `wcss` for a large set of `K`, how should I set the `Knee` algorithm's parameters to find the `K` with computing less number of `wcss`?

For smaller dataset when I increase the range for K, sometimes I get `ConvergenceWarning` so I limit the range to only compute `wcss` in the range mentioned in warning message. As a result, although I increase the sensitivity parameter (`s`) to 300 I am not able to decrease `wcss` to be less than my threshold. And for larger dataset I have tried to compute `wcss` for `k in range(1,1000,step)`, is there any other suggestion to find the K more efficiently?
Moreover, sometimes `Knee` could't find the best cluster. If it is the first time computing the number of cluster with `Knee` I set `K = 1`, otherwise I increase the previously found `k` by 1 (`K+=1`). What is the best heuristic here?

The following is the base code:

```
def computewcss(j, X, rang, step):
    wcss = [] 
    indexes = []
    for i in range(j, rang, step):
        kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = i, init = 'k-means++', random_state = 42) 
        kmeans.fit(X) 
        wcss.append(kmeans.inertia_)
        indexes.append(i)
    return wcss, indexes

wcss, x =computewcss(1, ds, rang, step) # rang and step are determined based on the dataset length at the begining
s = 1
ncluster = KneeLocator(x, wcss, S=s, curve='convex', direction='decreasing', online=True).knee 
distortion = wcss[x.index[ncluster]]
while (distortion > threshold and s < 250):                    
    s+=50
    start = rang + 1
    rang*=2 
    wcsstemp , xtemp = computewcss(start, ds, rang, step)
    wcss.extend(wcsstemp)
    x.extend(xtemp)
    ncluster = KneeLocator(x, wcss, S=s, curve='convex', direction='decreasing', online=True).knee 
    distortion = wcss[x.index[ncluster]]
```